# Doing an ANOVA, General Linear Model and linear regression with somewhat unequal variances - what should I do?

Tags: anova, multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity

I'm trying to analyze data that consists of the percentage of a specific area that is covered with a specific cell (postmortem human material) at three different age groups. Visually, the data appears to be approximately normally distributed, and this was confirmed with a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (p = 0.806).

However, the variances seem to be somewhat unequal. A Levene's test gives a significance level of p = 0.050, and visually the data do indeed seem to violate this assumption (see images below).

[image: Boxplot]
[image: Scatterplot]

My first question, I suppose, is whether this is indeed a problem for the tests I want to run (ANOVA to assess whether there is a difference - which there is -, a Games-Howell post-hoc to see which groups exactly differ, a linear regression for visual purposes, and a General Linear Model to test the influence of confounding variables). My group sizes are small but approximately equal: 6, 8, and 8 subjects in the three different age groups (this seems like a small number, but such numbers are actually quite common in human postmortem research and are sufficient to get reasonable power). I've read that ANOVA especially is quite robust when it comes to violations of assumptions, but I don't know about the General Linear Model.

About the ANOVA I'm not too worried, especially because it is only used to assess whether there is a difference - any conclusions are derived from the subsequent Games-Howell test. I suppose I could substitute it with a Welch's F test, as I've read that there's really no reason why you shouldn't use that, and it also gives a significant result. I'm just worried this may lead to confusion when publishing my results (I guess because most people aren't familiar with this test, for instance my supervisor), although of course I want to be as accurate and honest as possible.

My main worry is about the GLM. I'm using this to test the influence of two possible confounding variables on the dependent variable. Currently, the GLM gives non-significant results for the confounding variables (both p > 0.38), as expected. However, I'm wondering whether it is ok to use a GLM in this case, and if not, I'm not sure what alternative test I could use. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Finally, I'm using a linear regression for visual purposes (i.e. a scatterplot with fit line on top). Although it could be argued that the data perhaps isn't best represented *linearly*, I'm wondering whether this is a problem in relation to the heterogeneity of variances (keep in mind that I don't draw any conclusions from the linear regression: it is just a nice visual representation of the data).

I apologize for the length of this, I just wanted to make it as complete as possible! I've been struggling with this for a while now, unable to decide which course to take, and I thought I'd present the problem to people with more knowledge of statistics. Any comments and suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: Those sample sizes are really small to test normality.  Since the means appear to be different I would think you are applying K-S test separately.  If so why aren't there results from three tests?  The high p-value of 0.806 only indicates the difficulty at rejecting the null hypothesis of normality. On top of that detecting differences in variances is particularly difficult in small samples.

Comment: The sample sizes are also quite small to test differences in variance. I would suggest going ahead. You could always look at the residuals from the model afterwards if you are still worried.

Comment: This is just guesswork on my part but it looks to me like the first and second group (young and adult) have an outlier (the highest value in each case).  In that case it may be better to use the Brown-Forsythe test to test equality of variances as the median is the reference for measuring spread,

Comment: The p-value for the Levene test is borderline at the standard level of signicance.  The Brown-Forsythe test might give a higher p-value.  Then what do you do?  If you proceed to regression what are your predictors.  Then you have more parameters to estimate. I would worry regardless of what you do.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I agree that the sample sizes are very small and it is therefore very difficult to ascertain normality and equality of variance. I had initially tested the K-S on the entire sample (i.e. all 3 groups together); I admittedly hadn't thought about testing the groups separately, but I'll have a look. The Brown-Forsythe test does indeed give a higher p-value (p = 0.008), but I thought this was a test used to assess the difference between groups (like the Welch's test), instead of a test for equality of means?

Comment: The variance seems to increase with the mean (visually from the boxplot) so I would try a boxcox transform.